# How to clear all the rows without removing column header datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview bound to a datasource, all headers are **added to the columns collection** with a datapropertyname set.

When I clear the datagridview using

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = null;
```

The headers also disappear and when I fill the datagridview again the header texts are the database column names.

[Before refilling datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZHXV.png)

[After clearing and refilling the datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rCsg.png)

I do this to fill my datagridview

```
    MyDataGridView.DataSource = MyDatabase.MyTable.Select(rows => new
                {
                    ProductName = rows.Product.Name,
                    Quantity = rows.Quantity,
                    SalePrice = rows.SalePrice,
                    SubTotal = rows.Quantity * rows.SalePrice
                }).ToList();
```

So, is it possible to clear all rows without removing column header?

Comment: have you set `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;`?

Comment: you should show your code, at least the involved part, not only the query.

Comment: @mcNets how to show the code? when I put it here it's too long. Sorry noob question, first time posting in here.

Comment: I know, but .AutoGenerateColumns=false do the trick, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this command to clear all the rows:

```
MyDataGridView.Rows.Clear();
```

Comment: I try it, but I got this error









An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Rows collection cannot be programmatically cleared when the DataGridView control is data-bound to anything else than an IBindingList that supports change notification and allows deletion.

Comment: I found the issue, I just need to remove the __.ToList()__ at the end of the query. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
var dt = MyDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable;
dt.Rows.Clear();
MyDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```